# Define mid surface from a thin 3d surface shape

Tags: graphics, computational-geometry

At this moment, I need to define a mid surface between a thin 3D surface shape.

For example, I have the following thin 3D surface shape:

[image: surface_shape1]

[image: surface_shape2]

how to define a new surface in the middle of this kind shape?

Searched a lot on google, but did not find a very good way to do it. Anyone has a good idea on how to do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should have a look at the mathematical object named medial axis. There will be multiple issues:
  - you need an approximation of the medial axis,
  - the medial axis for an open object will not be what you want, and you will have to filter out some parts,
  - you want an implementation that gives a medial axis stable to noise.

Comment: Great, that’s exactly what I want, thank you!